# Error => /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Core -lQt5::Gui -lQt5::Test -lQt5::Concurrent -lQt5::OpenGL

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, qt5

I am getting these errors

```
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Core /usr/bin/ld: 
cannot find -lQt5::Gui /usr/bin/ld: 
cannot find -lQt5::Widgets /usr/bin/ld: 
cannot find -lQt5::Test /usr/bin/ld:
cannot find -lQt5::Concurrent /usr/bin/ld: 
cannot find -lQt5::OpenGL collect2: error: ld`
```

when i am `make`ing the project [https://github.com/estranho/facialSketchRecognition] .When i am making without `ENABLE_SAMPLES` i fotn get any error but when building Samples i m getting these errors.

https://github.com/estranho/facialSketchRecognition the project readme says cmake.. and make thats it but couldnt run any executable so building Samples is needed.

Comment: this error comes from linker, it says it cannot find several symbols. try to install qt5 `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev` or read full page here: https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/gt5 or https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/gt5

Answer (score 1):

You must:

- either install globally the Qt5 development library
- define your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to allow the system to find the Qt5 library, when performing the linking step (which is exactly what /usr/bin/ld is trying to do)

Under `Ubuntu` the package is named `qtdeclarative5-dev`.

Comment: how to define ld_library_path  (specifically to my case  ) ?

Comment: qt5 is already installed in  usr/bin/qt5 and addtionally i downloaded qt5 from their website . I run this command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/user/Qt5.12.0"`  { for the new downloaded one}  but still same error

Comment: You need the library, not the executable

Comment: i did  `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev` and its already installed but same error

Comment: Did you update your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable?

Comment: yes i updated  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/user/Qt5.12.0"` it didnt work so so tried this also `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/Qt5.12.0/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/lib` that too didnt work .What exactly i have to enter in the terminal ? screenshot - > https://imgur.com/gallery/4yHJYkU  . to install it globally i tried `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls`

Comment: There is no way the files of the installed package qtdeclarative5-dev, could be unser your home directory; so the specified path is not good. Try `dpkg-query -L qtdeclarative5-dev`, and adapt your PATH consequently.

Comment: this is what the output --> https://textuploader.com/1a8vm can you plz say what to do next .

Comment: Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Are you sure do the `export` instruction in the same Terminal where you are then launching your make? Can you show a complete log of your instructions, and their returns?

Comment: i change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" ` in `etc/environment` but still the error exists

Comment: yes i did `export` and make in same terminal heres a screenshot of it https://imgur.com/gallery/E7P5P2c

Comment: What gives `strace -f make`? We will see the exact path looked by `/usr/bin/ld` binary.